# In bootstrap datatable i have more then pages,in here i need page click function in jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

In datatable i have inline edit option for all columns ,if i do some edit but i didn't save that,that time i click on next page, show alertify function (before you leave this page please save else your changes will be loss)but this alertify comes after move to next page,but i need before enter to next page,once user click save or don't save then only move to next page.......my jquery code is here

```
    $('#myContacts').on('page.dt', function () {
        if ($("#hdnsaveChanges").val() == "1") {
            alertify.set({
                labels: {
                    cancel: "Don't Save",
                    ok: "Save "
                }
            });
            alertify.confirm("Do you want to move to another page. Your       changes have not been saved", function (e) {
                if (e) {
                    // $("#hdnsaveChanges").val("0");
                } else {
                }
            });
        }
    });
```